# JSPM - Is there a way or need to version the bundled files?

Tags: javascript, systemjs, jspm, es6-module-loader

I am using JSPM and SystemJS for loading and bundling front end code. What I wonder is that is there any need to version bundled files, if yes, how to do that because I couldn't find anything about versioning bundles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add some kind of "version" to the bundles so that if there are some changes on a bundle, the client will get the **latest** bundle - otherwise the client might get an older version because of browser caching or some other cache.

One possible way to do this is to add an **hash** to the name of the bundle so that if there are some changes, the hash will be different. However, for that to work, you will need to somehow map the name of the generated bundles when loading the page. One thing I usually do is to save a json file with the bundles names.

Comment: Yes. I read about that, you are right. I found a few thing about "cache busting" in systemjs, but none of them was a proper solution. Are you doing this is config file via jspm or systemjs configuration, or manually?

Comment: I do it manually. One easy way to do it is using [gulp-rev](https://github.com/sindresorhus/gulp-rev) to change the filename  (i.e. the bundle filename) and create a manifest file.

Comment: Not going to downvote because I'm not sure if there's a better solution, but all you really did with this answer was define how "revving" works... :P